# In PHP how can i run a mongo script using php mongo object

Tags: php, mongodb, execute

Using PHP i need to update my mongo content. My mongo collection structure is given below

```
{
"_id" :"5",
"rows": [
    { "id" : "aab", "value":100},
    { "id" : "dsc", "value":400},
    { "id" : "abc", "value":200},
    { "id" : "xyz", "value":300}
]
```

}

and the script for updating the above collection is working fine in Mongo Shell

```
db.Collection.find({"_id" : "5"}).forEach(function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
    db.VizSpreadsheet.update({
      "_id": data._id,
      "rows.id": data.rows[i].id
    }, {
      "$set": {
        "rows.$.status": 1
      }
    }, true, false);
  }
});
```

I am getting error 17287, "Can't canonicalize query:..." when the same code is used with db->execute() command. Can anybody help me to execute this code from php

Answer (score 0):

You wrote Collrction instead of collection.

```
db.Collrction.find(
```

should be

```
db.Collection.find(
```

Additionally, I remember mongodb PHP using arrays, not JSON strings. Try using the json_decode() function on your current queries to see if it works